# Why I get an error with GET before I entered values?

Tags: php

This is my first question here and I'm hardcore newbie in PHP, so don't be to harsh with me :D

I don't understand, why my code printing me an error without me even touched the form. How I can make this code print error only after submitting some values through form?

```
<?php 
$error = "";
if (isset($_GET['a'])) {
    $a = htmlentities($_GET['a']);
}
if (isset($_GET['b'])) {
    $b = htmlentities($_GET['b']);
}

if (empty($a)) {
    $error = "<b>Error:</b> You didn't enter 'a' or 'a' isn't a number<br>";
}
if (empty($b)) {
    $error .= "<b>Error:</b> You didn't enter 'b' or 'b' isn't a number<br>"; 
}
if ($a > $b) {
    $error = "<b>Error:</b>Number 'a' can't be bigger than 'b'<br>";
    } else {
    $sum = (int)$a + (int)$b;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Count sum of two number</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Count sum</h1>
        <br>
    <form action="4.php" method="GET">
    Enter a: <input type="text" name="a"><br><br>
    Enter b: <input type="text" name="b"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Count">
</form>
<br>
<b>Results:</b> 
<?php 
if (empty($error)) {
    echo $sum;} 
else {
    echo $error;
}
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect that echo $error will appear only after I submit values in the form, but at this moment I get it printed from the start.

Comment: on first load your `$_GET` is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the variables `$a` and `$b` are set before you compare. On the first load, `$_GET` would be empty and your variables `$a` and `$b` won't exist.

So you need to check that the variables exist before the condition check

```
if (isset($a) && isset($b) && ($a > $b)) {
    $error = "<b>Error:</b>Number 'a' can't be bigger than 'b'<br>";
    } else {
    $sum = (int)$a + (int)$b;
}
```

**PS**: You can rearrange the `isset($a) && isset($b)` condition as per your code requirement. This example is just to show how to use it.